# Change Font size of iOS app dynamically in all page from one page

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsnotificationcenter, uifont

I have an option to change the font size of my application from settings. If i change the size from settings, then it should affect all loaded pages in app.

SO I tried "NSNotificationCenter". I just added Observer in all classes , then I will fire notification from settings.

I have function called "updateUI"

```
-(void)updateUI{
    // here I will change font size of all UI controlls
}
```

Observer is

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateUI) name:"KFontSizeChanged" object:nil];
```

then I will call like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"KFontSizeChanged" object:self];
```

When Observer observe any new notification , then "updateUI" function will be called. there UI font size will be updated.
It works fine , but I want to know Is there any better solution to achieve this

also I have tried following

```
yourLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
```

According to this code , I will need iOS7 and above. but I need iOS 5 and above support. also I will need to go to iPhone settings to change size.

Can anyone Please Let me know is there any better solution to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you make category of **UIFont** and use this class and just change the size here and it will reflect in over all the app.

Comment: Thanks parvind. Let me try this.. I will get back to you soon.. :)

Comment: Hi Parvind, I am new to Objective c category. So I need help from you what to do in UIFont category class ? and how to change the font from class ?

Comment: @Manimurugan
#import "UIFont+Roundme.h"

implementation UIFont (Roundme)

+ (UIFont *)roundmeSetBoldFont:(float)fontsize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:fontsize];
}

+ (UIFont *)roundmeTextFont:(float)fontsize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaOblique" size:fontsize];
}
hi this the class code when you made category.and you have to import this class and set the font progmratically for each UIitem. first time it's time consuming but it's the better way in future if you want to change your font style and size then you just need to change in that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Parvind.. Can you help me that how to change font size in this category class from my view controller?

Comment: do i need to declare any fonts globally ?

Comment: you can save float value in nsuserdefaults,first time you show default value next time you can change value that valuse from setting.and in category class extract size value from userdefaults. :)

Comment: Thanks parvind.I am still confused that should I call "roundmeSetBoldFont" function from my view controller every time user changed the font size from settings?

Comment: copy this method in category class  +(float)fontSize{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"fontSize"]) {
        return  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"fontSize"];

    }
    
    return 12.0;
    
}   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:14.0 forKey:@"fontSize"]; and you can set value like this and call this in method     return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:[self fontSize]];

Comment: ok parvind thanks for your help.. I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SuperClass (lets say MasterVC) for all your viewControllers, & you can edit/customize fonts & all other properties from a single place .. :)